# bind rows over similar data frames where one data frame is missing columns.

Tags: r

I'd like to combine data frames with similar named columns and introduce NA's where one of the data frames is missing column values (in this case the z variable is missing in df2).

```
>df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                   y = 1:10,
                   z = 1:10)

>df2 <- data.frame(y = 11:20,
                   x = 11:20)

#my output could look like this with NA's added where there are missing columns. 
>data.frame(x = 1:20,
           y = 1:20,
           z = c(1:10, rep(NA, 10)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadley offers a nice function for that:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(df1, df2)

#    x  y  z
#1   1  1  1
#2   2  2  2
#3   3  3  3
#4   4  4  4
#5   5  5  5
#6   6  6  6
#7   7  7  7
#8   8  8  8
#9   9  9  9
#10 10 10 10
#11 11 11 NA
#12 12 12 NA
#13 13 13 NA
#14 14 14 NA
#15 15 15 NA
#16 16 16 NA
#17 17 17 NA
#18 18 18 NA
#19 19 19 NA
#20 20 20 NA
```

Comment: Hadley offers a nice function for everything.

Comment: @RichardScriven He offers many nice functions, I'd agree with that.